# Parsing NBA reference with python beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape out the miscellaneous stats table from this site http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2016.html using python and beautiful soup.  This is the basic code so far I just want to see if it is even reading the table but when I do print table I just get none.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2016.html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

table = soup.find('table', id='misc_stats')
print table
```

When I inspect the html on the webpage itself, the table that I want appears with this symbol in front `<!--` and the html text is green for the portion.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<!--` is the start of a comment and `-->` is the end in html so just remove the comments before you parse it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
comm = re.compile("<!--|-->")

html = requests.get("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2016.html").content
cleaned_soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub("<!--|-->","", html))


tableStats = cleaned_soup.find('table', {'id':'team_stats'})

print(tableStats)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Worked great.